# Software for combining non-rectangular images on a large sheet

Tags: images, automation, image-processing, printing

I would like to automate process of creating batch sheets for printing filled with a lot of non-rectangular images. These images (stickers) have various shapes and different sizes.

Source images are in PNG format with transparency and as far as I know, I should add manually cutting paths (polygons) in image-editing software like GIMP or Photoshop.

Is there any script/library (in any programming language) that would do this task in the most optimal way? I would like to fit all images on the smallest surface possible.

Thank you in advance for giving some help!